# Unable to add options to the select dynamically from json

Tags: javascript, html, select

i have this `select`, with id `category` and `product`. If a choose one option in the select `category`, the other should list all products in that category.

```js
  var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  console.log('value: '+e.value);
  for(var x in json) {
    console.log(x+' -> id: '+json[x]['id']);
    var all = document.getElementById(target).querySelector("#all");
    document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById(target).appendChild(all);

    var data = json[x];

    if(e.value == '*') {
      console.log('add ('+data['id']+', '+data['nome']+')');
      var child = document.createElement("option");
      child.setAttribute("value", data['id']);
      child.innerText = data['nome'];
      document.getElementById(target).appendChild(child);
    } else {
      if(data['categoria'].id == e.value) {
        console.log('add ('+data['id']+', '+data['nome']+')');
        var child = document.createElement("option");
        child.setAttribute("value", data['id']);
        child.innerText = data['nome'];
        document.getElementById(target).appendChild(child);
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
  <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm">
            Category:
            <select class="form-control" id="category" data-target="product" th:attr="data-url=@{/produto/listBy.json}" onchange="fill_produtos(this);">
              <option value="*">All</option>
              <option th:each="option : ${categories}" th:value="${option.id}">
                <span th:each="t : ${option.nome}" th:if="${#strings.equals(#strings.substringBefore(t.idioma,','), #strings.replace(#locale,'_','-'))}" th:href="@{/categoria/__${t.conteudo}__}" th:text="${t.conteudo}"></span>
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            Produto:
            <select class="form-control" id="product">
              <option id="all" value="*">All</option>
              <option th:each="option : ${produtos}" th:value="${option.id}" th:text="${option.nome}"></option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            Date Range: <input type="date" class="form-control"> a <input type="date" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
```

Right now, this is not happening as expected. I have this 3 categories (named `one`, `two` and `three`), each one with 1 product (`prod1`, `prod2` and `prod3`). I select categories `one` or `two`, no products are listed on the other select; if I select category `three` or `all`, only the product `three` are listed on the other select.

Except that the debug code (the `console.log`) added to the function seems to follow the right path when I click each option on `category`: if I click `one`, only the message inside the `if(data['categoria'].id == e.value)` is shown; same for `two` and `three`. If click `all`, all messages are shown, as expected, due the instruction telling to do so after `if(e.value == '*')`.

Anyone can see what I am doing wrong here? I know I am missing something, but I can't see what is.

Comment: There is a bunch of stuff there I don't recognize. For example: th:each="option : ${produtos}" th:... -- what is this? Is this native JavaScript? If not, perhaps you could mention the library/framework/whatever it is you are using? Perhaps as a tag, maybe in the title? Just a thought.

Comment: that's just thymeleaf tags, do not have any influence on the subject of the question. you can ignore them and the code still works (this tags only generate a list of normal ´option´ tags inside the select, and the ´data-url´ tag).